# I don't know the authentication password to download stuff

Tags: password, downloads, reboot, authentication, reset

I got this computer from some one online and I don't know any of the passwords I manly need to just reset the authentication password is there a way to reset it without the authentication password

Comment: *"from some one online"* - you should create installation media, format the disk, and reinstall the operating system.   You have no idea what's on that device.  It would not be very wise to start using it without a reformat.

Comment: they told me that it was a school computer that they didn't want and they could not factory reset it.

Comment: @MikeyHerobrine Welcome! Follow the [Installation guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview), install Ubuntu from scratch. When you run the live media installer, check your hardware specs, or google the model of your machine to see what flavour of Ubuntu is best for your hardware.

Comment: As others have said, a new install of Ubuntu is a good idea.  You will have a clean and known supported system.  The version on that computer might be out of date, depending on age of it.

Comment: "*they told me that it was a school computer that they didn't want and they could not factory reset it*" -- IMO that's even more shady...  If a person was dishonest and selling laptops preloaded with keyloggers, that might be exactly how they advertise it.

Answer (score -1):

you can retrieve your password by unlocking the root user ... for this, you have to enter in  recovery mode and then reset the root password

For entering in rescue mode

1.restart your computer

2. press shift or Esc what is work for you ...
3. Then choose an advance option

4.then use down arrow key for selecting root  option

Now you can see root shell
fire command

root@ubuntu: mount -o remount,rw /

after that
change roots' password
root@ubuntu: passwd  [New Password]
retype password

Now you can also change your administrative password by firing a few commands
or you can login into root in GUI mode and then change it.